# How to show all sub-categories articles?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Choosing menu item type to "Category Blog,List All Categories, and Category List" would result all subcategories link not direct to all articles of sub-categories.

But I want to show directly the all articles of sub-categories.

```
main-category
   sub-categories
       cat-1
            article
            article
            .......
       cat-2
            article
            article
            .......
       cat-3
            article
            article
            .......
```

Now, how to show all articles of main-category?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Menu Item Settings: Blog Layout -> Choose Include Subcategories "ALL"

#### UPDATE

FYI: This behavior can be set also globally for all Blog Layout Menu Items.
 
In Article Manager Options -> Blog / Featured Layouts Tab -> Include Subcategories.

Comment: I can't see "ALL" option. Where is it/

Comment: Sorry, forgot to ask: Joomla version ?

Comment: joomla 2.5 is tagged in question.

Comment: Oh! I found it inside blog layout option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

first, find the column `params` in your database table `###_extensions` which row name is `com_content`.

update the inner value in the JSON string, `"show_subcategory_content":0` to `"show_subcategory_content":1` that mean for 1 level subcategory support.
This is a global configuration.

If you just want one menu item to support that, find the item in table `###_menu` and add `"show_subcategory_content":1` in `params` which works.